# IEnumerator WaitForSeconds not executing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This should have taken just 30 seconds to implement yet has taken over 3 hours so far and still not fixed. I have a OnTriggerEnter2D with a Collider2D. The code works correctly, but for some reason when trying to add a Coroutine with any sort of wait time is causing the wait time or anything after to not be executed.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Player player = other.GetComponent<Player>();

            if (player != null && !player.sheildActive && !player.shieldSpawned)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);

                player.sheildActive = true;
                player.shieldSpawned = true;

                _UIManager = GameObject.Find("UI_Manager").GetComponent<UIManager>();
                _UIManager._messageText.text = "Shield Active"; //working
            }
            else
            {
                _UIManager = GameObject.Find("UI_Manager").GetComponent<UIManager>();
                _UIManager._messageText.text = "Shield already active"; //working
                StartCoroutine(UpdateMessageTextCoroutine());
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateMessageTextCoroutine()
    {
        // Anything added here works correctly
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // nothing happening here
        // debug.log here nothing happens 
        _UIManager = GameObject.Find("UI_Manager").GetComponent<UIManager>();
        _UIManager._messageText.text = "TEST"; //not working
    }
}
```

Comment: so for confirmation you get the "Shield already active" message? your game has not changed time in any way, (dear god why find UI_Manager every time?) but you arent getting your TEST message?

Comment: @BugFinder I am completely new to Unity and always run into issues with objects and scripts not being found so I am overly cautious haha. Adding it above the wait time, the text updates correctly, but adding it below the Wait, it never gets changed. Something is wrong with my yield wait time, but have no idea what it could be.

Comment: @shingo Thanks so much! Had a read-through and noticed the global game object answer. Changed up the code and moved the co-routine to the player file instead, then referenced it through an UpdateMessageText method, worked great! Thanks for providing this link!